# Regular languages and intersection

Tags: regular-language

Let L be a language and R an infinite regular one. If L intersection R is a regular language, then L is a regular one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $L = \{1^p : p \text{ is prime}\}$. $R = \{1^{2n} : n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: That's my feeling too. :) However, I am a bit confused. As far as I know, the intersection of two regular languages is a regular language too, because of closure. So here, the problem is that R is an infinite one?
An example would be very helpful. :) (I saw your edit now) Can you please explain why the example you provided works? :)

Comment: The intersection of two regular languages is regular. But what we have here is a different question: If $L$ is any language, $R$ regular and $L \cap R$ regular, is $L$ regular? The answer is "not necessarily" as demonstrated by my example.

Comment: And since: The empty language Ø is a regular language, I am convinced, bravo! :)

Comment: Well $2$ is the only even prime number, so $L \cap R = \{11\}$, which is regular. But you get the idea.

Comment: Oops missed that. A last thing, why is L non-regular?

Comment: It's a standard example found in many books. Just apply the pumping lemma. See here for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181230

Comment: Convinced!Thanks!

Comment: To understand with intuition: simple things cannot give complex things by intersection, but the other way around is possible: complex things can give simpler ones. It is quite natural.